# Graphical apps showing distortion in VirtualBox

Tags: 22.04, graphics, virtualbox

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on my VirtualBox on Windows 10. Graphical apps are not working. I tried bless and stegsolve. Since both apps have a GUI, both gave a distorted GUI which is unusable.

Stegsolve:

[image: Stegsolve]

Comment: insall vbox guest additions

Comment: @petep guest additions were installed when i installed ubuntu